# Disable Ubuntu shortcuts

Tags: c++, glfw

On Ubuntu when capturing keyboard input with GLFW some keys like `LEFT ALT` are not passed to my window. Instead some desktop functionality is triggered like the dashboard search in case of the alt key.

How do I run a windowed game on Ubuntu, using all keys available on the keyboard, without telling the user how to turn off Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts all together at game start?

Answer (score -1):

[This answer should hopefully annihilate those pesky shortcuts for you:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455397/disable-ubuntu-keyboard-shortcuts)

> In System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts
>
> Find the shortcut you're trying to disable, click on it to set a new
>   shortcut, then pressing Backspace will disable that shortcut.

As for your players, I don't know of a way to default them off. I'd advise picking different keys to circumvent the issue. Some players might not want them off anyway if they were playing the game and quickly wanted to tab out.